# i want that when i click on parent (div) it should count how many times i have clicked , help me in this matter

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created a div called parent and in that I have done simple css.

i want that when I clicked on parent then inside the parent div it should show that who many time I have clicked on the parent (div)

kindly help in this matter

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    var parent = document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var x = 0;
        x += 1;

        parent.innerHTML = x;

    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You provided code and what you expect the code to do, but did did not provide what is currently wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error that says parent is not defined.

First define `parent`, then use its variable to create your click event. Also you need to move the defining variable for your increment `x` outside of the click events function so you are not resetting it with each click...

If you wish to append the incremented number to the `textContent`, then also define your `textContent` outside the function, then you can use a literal to join them for your `innerHTML`.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent")
let x = 0;
let content = parent.textContent
parent.addEventListener("click", () => {
  x++;
  parent.innerHTML = `<h1>${content}${x}</h1>`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some issues in your code:

1. As you are declaring the variable inside the event handler function the value is not updating, you should declare that in the global scope.
2. You can refer the current element using `this` key word as `parent` is not referring to the element you are thinking, it is having the value `undefined`.
3. On each click you can remove the last character from the string and add the counter value. I will also suggest you to use `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if the content is plain text (not htmlString).

You can try the following way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    var x = 0;
    var element = document.querySelector(".parent");
    var pText = element.textContent;
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {        
        x += 1;
        this.textContent = pText + x;
    });
    
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What does var parent = ... actually do (to the variable)? A written explanation of the code would be useful.

Comment: @AHaworth, thank you for the suggestion, added some explanation:)